# css html При повороте изображение размывается

Tags: html, css, jpeg

Проблема в следующем: необходимо поврнуть изображение на 45 градусов( по часовой). В результате поворота, изображение( формат: **jpg**, представляющее собой уже не квадрат, а ромб) становится менее чётким. Можно ли с этим что-нибудь сделать?

Ну а в общем, проблема в следующем: необходимо получить кнопку( точнее, рисунок или блок с background-image, обёрнутый в ссылку) не с квадратной, а с ромбической областью клика. 
Мной это реализовано было так: взято исходное изображение, обёрнуто в ссылку, ссылка повёрнута на 45 градусов вправо для получения ромба. Ромб получился, но возникла упомянутая проблема

[image: Исходное и.]
[image: Повёрнутое изображение]

Comment: Это не решается.

Comment: Это проблема трансформа, на сколько я знаю у этого нет решения. Что бы решить - поверни изображение в редакторе изображений(фотошоп...) и вставь уже его.

Comment: @Levelleor , так и сделал. Хотя, к превеликому сожалению, мусора таки прибавилось.  
Надо сказать, эта проблема трансформа оказалась полной внезапностью.

Comment: Добро пожаловать в мир боли при использовании ромбо подобных конструкций.